# How can i alter this query return the average over all overs in the db. mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
db.temperature.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
      "$and": [
        { "date": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-10-12T22:00:00Z") }},
        { "date": { "$lt": ISODate("2017-10-12T22:59:99Z") }}
      ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": { "$hour": "$date" },
      "temperature": {
        "$avg": "$temperature"
      }
    }}
  ])
```

The data looks like

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5df25dd648bfdfee3906e0cd"),
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-12T22:00:00Z"),
        "power" : 39
}
```

There is a record for every minute and i am trying to get the average over every hour in the database. This returns the average over a specific hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the `$match` part of your query:

```
db.temperature.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
      "_id": { "$hour": "$date" },
      "temperature": {
        "$avg": "$temperature"
      }
    }}
  ])
```

You can see the output of this query, with some sample data, by clicking on `run` in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lJAe_LrdFSv).